# Get the local time using js timezone and format it with moment JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I would like to format a date using moment JS which I get the date from js timezone library. anybody to help.

Following the code, I have written:

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var timezone =tz.name();
var timess = moment().tz(timezone).format();
var times_new = moment(timess).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

Also I have include jstz.min.js and moment-with-locales.min.js

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted? What does this code print? What do you expect?

Comment: I would like to format today's date using moment from my timezone. So, I retrieved timezone using jstz.min lib and want to format the current date using moment.

Answer (score 0):

To use moment time zones, you need to add the [Moment Time Zone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

After that you can use the moment `tz` method. You can avoid the two passages:

```
var timess = moment().tz(timezone).format();
var times_new = moment(timess).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

And write all in one line:

```
var timess = moment().tz(timezone).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

Because `moment().tz(timezone)` returns a moment object.